# How to make a Search Filter in React

Tags: reactjs

Hi i want my search bar to filter through my data in react js but it shows this:
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, Nom, Email, Profession, Date_naiss, Telephone, Date_adhession}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
any suggestions pls

Here is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Axios from 'axios';
import './Parent.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Parent(){
    const [Info,getInfo] = useState([])
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("")
    const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([])

    const inputEl = useRef("")
    useEffect(() => {
        getAllInfo();
      }, []);
  
  
      const getAllInfo = (props) =>{
         Axios.get('http://localhost:3005/adherents')
         .then((response) => {
        
           getInfo(response.data)
         })
         .catch(error => console.log("error"))
      }
      const searchHandler = (search) =>{
         setSearch(search);
         if (search !== "") {
             const newList = Info.filter((user,index) => {
               return Object.values(user).join("").toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()); 
             });
             setSearchResults(newList);
         }else{
             setSearchResults(Info)
             
         }
      }
      const getSearch = () =>{
          searchHandler(inputEl.current.value)
      }
    return(
        <div className="Info">
            <div className="PY">
             <h1>Rechercher les Adherents</h1>
             <div className="ui search">
                <div className="ui icon input">
                  <input ref={inputEl} text="text" 
                  placeholder="search" className="prompt" 
                  value={search} onChange={getSearch}></input>
                  <i className="search icon"></i>
                </div>
             </div>
    <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Nom</th>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
        <th scope="col">Numero_Tel</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                
          { Info.map((user,index)=>
               <tr>
                   <th scope="row"> {index+1} </th>
                   <td> {user.Nom} </td>
                   <td> {user.Email} </td>
                   <td> {user.Telephone} </td>
                   <td>
                       <Link class="btn btn-primary btn-space" to={{pathname:"./SetInfo", user: user.Nom}} >View</Link>
                       <Link class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-space" to={{pathname:"./EditUser", user: user}} >Edit</Link>
                       <Link class="btn btn-danger btn-space">Delete</Link>
                   </td>
               
               </tr>
           ) 
          }
        
        
    </tbody>
        <div>
        { search.length < 1 ? Info  : searchResults}
        </div>


</table>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Parent;
```

Comment: What does this have to do with nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

`{ search.length < 1 ? Info  : searchResults}` this line causes the error.

`const [Info,getInfo] = useState([])` here You declare `Info` as an array, which can NOT be rendered. If You want to show something, You should keep a `string` in the `Info`. Otherwise, You must use `map` or something like that to iterate through (exactly like You have done in Your table) the `Info` array like this
`{Info.map(item) => <h4>{item.Email}</h4>}`. The same goes for `searchResults`, which is also an array.

Modifying the code like this `{search.length < 1 ? Info?.length  : searchResult?.length}` might be the solution for You.

Or If You want to show the results in a table try something like this.
`{ ( search.length < 1 ? Info  : searchResults).map(user, index) => ...`
This way, the search results will be rendered if the `search.length` is greater than 1

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work it instead duplicated the table